# Enabling background server push notifications in Ionic2 / Cordova application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, notifications, ionic2

I wish to be able to push notifications from my **own asp.net Web API REST service** to be received by an Ionic 2 application, whether or not it is running, perhaps show a notification and then be able to click on this to open the Ionic2 application. I know nothing about Mobile notifications and want to know if I am on the right track.

I see there is an Ionic Native plugin [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/background-mode/) to enable the app itself to run in background, but going [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#bangbang-store-compliance-bangbang) for more information, there is the following statement...

*Store Compliance ‼️
The plugin focuses on enterprise-only distribution and may not compliant with all public store vendors.*

This makes me think I will have problem particularly with the apple store.

I then wondered if the other option is to run a separate **service** (perhaps using Xamarin as it seems to be able to do this) on the Android/iOS devices, send the notifications to this, and then have the service open the application perhaps using the [Deep Linking](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/)

Alternatively, I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/868000/Push-Notification-For-Windows-iOS-Android-Quick-Ea) article on something called PushSharp. I am a little confused with this as it used this library, and also seems to use **SignalR** (why both - not sure where the SignalR comes into it)

Also, is mentions "Google Cloud Messaging for Android". Even though I am sending notifications from me own server, is this something I use as an "in between", ie my server sends notifications via the "Google Cloud Messaging"?

Am I on the right track here, do I need a separate service, or the Mobile platforms have notifications built in, so I can use this can have this open my perhaps not running application?

Thanks in advance for any pointers here

Comment: any progress on this ? We are looking into using a PushSharp/ionic2 combination but not sure where to start.

Comment: Not yet but still active researching. So far looks like we either use https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging as an inbetween or have our own separate service to receive the notifications and then launch our app. As far as I have seen the service can't be done in Cordova so if we do may try using Xamarin for just the service,  otherwise use the native language   (service would be small with no UI so should not be too difficult)